# Dynamically selection of Column Name

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping, dynamic-sql

I want to select **Column Name** which has non null and non zero value. So any **column name** which has 0 or NULL should not be displayed in the output grid

**I have the Source table as below**

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    col5D   Col6D   Col7D   Col8D

Abc     0       1       John    0       0       0       0       
Abc     1       2       John    1       0       0       0
Abc     2       3       John    0       0       0       0
Abc     3       4       John    0       1       0       0
Xyz     0       1       Ron     0       0       0       0       
Xyz     1       2       Ron     0       0       0       0
Xyz     2       3       Ron     0       0       1       0
Xyz     3       4       Ron     0       0       0       0
```

I want to group by `Col1` and Display `Col1, MIN(Col2), MIN(Col3), MIN(Col4)` and `ColRes` as (Name of the column with value more than 0)

**Expected Output as below**:

```
   col1     col2    col3    col4    ColRes  

    Abc     1       2       John    Col5D
    Abc     3       4       John    Col6D
    Xyz     2       3       Ron     Col7D
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: Column-4 is also the Name as Col1, So why are you making it MIN-Value? is there any requirement like that?

Comment: @im_one min is so that I can group using Col1

Comment: But As per your data it seems like first name and last name!!! so you can add both the Columns in GROUP-BY

Comment: @im_one no its not first name and last name, its first name and department :)

Comment: Please change your Expected output/Question for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
select col1, col2, col3, col4
  , case when col5D > 0 then 'col5d' when col6D > 0 then 'col6d' when col7D > 0 then 'col7d' when col8D > 0 then 'col8d' else '' end
from table1
where col5d > 0 or col6D > 0 or col7D > 0 or col8D > 0
```

Comment: @Duffer: Are you sure this query is as per your EXPECTED OUTPUT shown in your question? bcz this will result you Only 2-Rows. Because GROUP-BY names are Common. So it will merge result Row-1 & Row-2

Answer (score 1):

Your question about `GROUP-BY` & OUTPUT result are confusing.
B'cz `GROUP-BY` will merge *Result Row-1&2*.

But for your better result you can try below queries for the surety.

**Create Table Definition**

```
Create table Table1
(
  col1 varchar(10),
  col2  int,
  col3 int,
  col4 varchar(10),
  col5D int,
  col6D int,
  col7D int,
  col8D int
)
GO
insert into Table1
values('Abc',0,1,'John',0,0,0,0)       
GO
insert into Table1
values('Abc',1,2,'John',1,0,0,0)
GO
insert into Table1
values('Abc',2,3,'John',0,0,0,0)
GO
insert into Table1
values('Abc',3,4,'John',0,1,0,0)
GO
insert into Table1
values('Xyz',0,1,'Ron',0,0,0,0)       
GO
insert into Table1
values('Xyz',1,2,'Ron',0,0,0,0)
GO
insert into Table1
values('Xyz',2,3,'Ron',0,0,1,0)
GO
insert into Table1
values('Xyz',3,4,'Ron',0,0,0,0)
```

**Result ①→** As Shown in **Expected Result**, You should try this query.

```
SELECT
    COL1, COL2, COL3, COL4,
    CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(COL5D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL5D'
            WHEN ISNULL(COL6D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL6D'
            WHEN ISNULL(COL7D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL7D'
            WHEN ISNULL(COL8D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL8D' END
     As ColRes
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ISNULL(COL5D,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(COL6D,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(COL7D,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(COL8D,0) > 0
```

Then Output will be: (avoid use of `GROUP-BY`)

[image]

**Result ②→** As Shown in **Question To Use** `GROUP-BY` then You should try this query.

```
SELECT
    COL1, MIN(COL2) AS COL2, MIN(COL3) AS COL3, COL4 AS COL4,
    MAX(CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(COL5D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL5D'
            WHEN ISNULL(COL6D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL6D'
            WHEN ISNULL(COL7D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL7D'
            WHEN ISNULL(COL8D,0) > 0 THEN 'COL8D' END
       ) As ColRes
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ISNULL(COL5D,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(COL6D,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(COL7D,0) > 0 OR ISNULL(COL8D,0) > 0
GROUP BY COL1,COL4
```

Then Output will be: (Use of `GROUP-BY`)

[image]

***Note***: Please correct your expected result/question and check on the correct result as an Answer, or else other users will be confused.